# Open pop up in the same, current page in IE11

Tags: vba, popup

Is there a way to use VBA to force a pop up (generated by clicking on a link on a website) to open in the same window of the website on which your VBA code clicks the link? So the pop up actually replaces the original website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bond taught me a workaround here - instead of clicking on the link that will result in the pop-up, you can always just re-navigate to this link by referencing its href (as in the source code of the original page you'd click on). This keeps the window the same but changes the page to display the pop-up